# When opening modal, my main view turns black MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I implemented a modal window with partial view using bootstrap, the problem is that when I open my modal it leaves the main view blocked, giving it a black color

[image: Modal]

When I inspect the item with the console of my browser, I can not find the control that gives the property of the fund to the manners

[image: Console]

Incorporate a template of [Boostrapwatch](https://bootswatch.com/) for some time in my project, I enclose the code:

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
          transform: translate(0, -25%);
}


.modal.show .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-dialog-centered {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100% - (0.5rem * 2));
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #4E5D6C;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;

}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
}


.modal-header .close {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: -1rem -1rem -1rem auto;
}

.modal-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

I have to put some additional class in my modal window?

```
 <div class="modal" id="myModalEditar">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Editar Producto</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="EditModalBody">

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

do I have to create another css property? What is wrong with this? any help for me?

Comment: inspect the page again and look for a `div` just before the closing `</body>` tag that has a class of like "modal-backdrop" or "overlay" or something. Set that to display none if you don't want the overlay.

Comment: Prepare your answer to mark it as correct! @zgood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Bootstrap modal backdrop you'll want to hide. To do so you could add this style:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
}
```

or change the opacity:

```
.modal-backdrop {
    opacity: 0;
}
```